# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/STAXEventReader

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, dom4j

I'm using JPA + Hibernate 5. And I have a problem with dom4j.

Thank you very much.

Class Empleado.java-->

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLEADO")
public class Empleado implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COD_EMPLEADO")
    private Long codigo;

    @Column(name = "APELLIDOS")
    private String apellidos;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "FECHA_NACIMIENTO")
    private Date fechaNacimiento;

    public Empleado() {

    }

    public Empleado(Long codigo, String apellidos, String nombre, Date fechaNacimiento) {

        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Empleado [codigo=" + codigo + ", apellidos=" + apellidos + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", fechaNacimiento="
                + fechaNacimiento + "]";
    }



}
```

Class TestEmpleado:-->

```
public class TestEmpleados {

    private static EntityManager manager;

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistencia");
        manager = emf.createEntityManager();

        List<Empleado> empleados = (List<Empleado>) manager.createQuery("FROM Empleado").getResultList(); 
        System.out.println(empleados.size() + "Empleados");


    }

}
```

This is my persistence.xml:-->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="Persistencia">

    <class>es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Empleado</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem/test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />


            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And at last this is my POM:-->

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>es.makigas</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-ejemplo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.191</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>





    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

When I execute the TestEmpleados I get the following error-->

```
mar 17, 2017 11:18:07 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: Persistencia
    ...]
mar 17, 2017 11:18:07 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
mar 17, 2017 11:18:07 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
mar 17, 2017 11:18:07 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/STAXEventReader
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at es.makigas.hibernate.tests.TestEmpleados.main(TestEmpleados.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.io.STAXEventReader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.io.STAXEventReader`. And? it cant find the class!!

Comment: I have added in Maven Dependencies Dom4j-1.6.1jar. And in Java Build Path there is the jar Dom4j-1.6.1 too.

Comment: and fix your use of javax.persistence. You have JPA 1.0 there, but your JPA provider implements JPA 2.1!

Comment: I fixed this problem changing JPA1.0 by JPA 2.1, but it's still not working. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Hibernate core 5.1.0.Final include dom4j-1.6.1 jar which throws this error. To fix this, need to exclude dom4j-1.6.1 from hibernate-core and include dom4j-1.6 in your pom.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <!-- Exclude SLF4j to avoid version conflicts (we have 1.6.6, this drags 
            in 1.6.1) -->
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <!-- Exclude dom4j to avoid version conflicts (we have 1.6, this drags 
            in 1.6.1) -->
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- add dom4j in the correct version -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You have to add the dom4j in the correct version. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I see in pom.xml that two dependencies are mismatching - Hibernate 5.1.0 and JPA 1.0.2
If you want to make use of Hibernate 5.1.0 then you should use JPA 2.1. Please make this change and it should work fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added your solution, but I have the same problem: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/STAXEventReader.

Comment: Please check in namespace as there I can see you are using persistence 2.0 version. Please change that as well to 2.1.

Comment: Hi, 
I added the version 2.1, but I have the same problem with the Dom4j.

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: I mean in persistence.xml namespace where persistence version is mentioned as 2.0 : <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

Comment: I added: version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

And now I have the following error:

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units
 at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:84)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactor
Thank You! :)

Comment: I hope you have made the following way: <persistence xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"; version="2.1" xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">; And looks like you missed Maven Install. Please let me know if you still face the issue after this.

Comment: I have the same in my persistence.xml that you posted. And I don't know why I have this error? Thank you very much again! :)

<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
 version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

Comment: I solve the problem using Hibernate 5.1.0 then you should use JPA 2.1. I put the incorrect version of JPA. Thank you!